# How do I...Count the no of records inserted.

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting the values form excel in datatable then finally i'm updating/Inserting the record in database.

Every thing is working fine but what i need is once finishing all the records it should display the message to the user as ..no of records inserted.

and also while inserting some time it is throwing an error as

```
 String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Eg:
20 records inserted.

Here is my code:

```
 private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
       {
           String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CARGONETConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
           //file upload path
           string FolderPath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"]);
           //file name
           string FileName = lblFileName.Text;
           //Create connection string to Excel work book

           string conStr = "";
           switch (Extension)
           {
               case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                   conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FolderPath + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                   break;
               case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                   conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FolderPath + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";
                   break;
           }

            conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
            OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

           //Get the name of First Sheet
            connExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string SheetName = ddlSheets.SelectedValue.ToString();
            connExcel.Close();

           //Read Data from First Sheet
            connExcel.Open();
            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
            oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
            oda.Fill(dt);
            connExcel.Close();

           //Bind to Database

           int count=0;
            using (LQTransAgentSeaFreightRateDataContext DB = new LQTransAgentSeaFreightRateDataContext())
            {
                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var newSFR = new TB_TransAgentSeaFreightRate_2
                    {
                        POD = r["POL"].ToString(),
                        POL = r["POD"].ToString(),
                        Forwarder = r["FORWARDER"].ToString(),
                        ForwarderReference = r["FORWARDER REFERENCE"].ToString(),
                        ShippingLine = r["SHIPPING LINE"].ToString(),
                        ContainerType = r["CONTAINER TYPE"].ToString(),
                        ContainerSize = r["CONTAINER SIZE"].ToString(),
                        ValidFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(r["VALIDITY FROM"].ToString()),
                        ValidTo = Convert.ToDateTime(r["VALITITY TO"].ToString()),
                        BasicRate = Convert.ToDecimal(r["BASIC RATE"]),
                        PAF = Convert.ToDecimal(r["PAF "]),
                        CAF = Convert.ToDecimal(r["CAF"]),
                        PSS = Convert.ToDecimal(r["PSS"]),
                        TotalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(r["TOTAL AMOUNT"]),
                        FreeDays = Convert.ToDecimal(r["FREE DAYS"]),
                        CreditDays = r["CREDIT DAYS"].ToString(),
                        NITDeposit = r["NIT DEPOSIT"].ToString(),
                        tASF_NUIsActive = 1,
                        tASF_mCMP_NUUniqueId = mobjGenlib.ConvertLong(TXTCompanyID.Text)

                    };
                    DB.TB_TransAgentSeaFreightRate_2s.InsertOnSubmit(newSFR);
                    DB.SubmitChanges();
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Up.GetType(), "ALERT", "alert('Saved Successfully');", true);
            //Bind Data to GridView
            dg_AgentSFR.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
            dg_AgentSFR.DataSource = dt;
            dg_AgentSFR.DataBind();
            //savedatafromgv();

       }
```

please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it throws an error at `ValidFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(r["VALIDITY FROM"].ToString()` and `Valitity to`. Please provide as with the value when it crashes. You should probalby use a try parse.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
This message could be because of incorrect date format in the input excel file. Try using Datetime.parseexact where appropriate.

Comment: Ya Exactly It was the place where It throws an error . It throws an error only after complete inserting all records. :(

Comment: Can any one say how to count the total no of records inserted?

Comment: dt.Rows.Count() would tell how many rows available in dataset..It may helpful to determine the total no of records inserted

Comment: Welcome, I have posted the same as answer. just mark as answer if it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dt.Rows.Count() would tell how many rows available in dataset..It will helpful to determine the total no of records inserted